# Compute the (multiplicative) inverse of $4x+3$ in the field $\frac {\Bbb F_{11}[x]}{\langle x^2+1 \rangle}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, quotient-spaces

So I am finding a polynomial $px+q$ ($p,q \in \Bbb F_{11}$) which is multiplicative inverse of $4x+3$ in $\frac {\Bbb F_{11}[x]}{\langle x^2+1 \rangle}$.

i.e. $[(4x+3)+\langle x^2+1 \rangle][(px+q)+\langle x^2+1 \rangle]=1+\langle x^2+1 \rangle$

$\Rightarrow$

$(4x+3)(px+q)+\langle x^2+1 \rangle=1+\langle x^2+1 \rangle$

$\Rightarrow$

$4px^2+(4q+3p)x+3q+\langle x^2+1 \rangle=1+\langle x^2+1 \rangle$.

We see that the remainder,when $(4x+3)(px+q)$ is divided by $x^2+1$, is $1$.
So by Division algorithm,

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
4p \\[-3pt]
x^2+1 \enclose{longdiv}{4px^2+(4q+3p)x+3q} \\[-3pt]
\underline{4px^2+4p} \\[-3pt]
(4q+3p)x+(3q-4p) \\[-3pt]
\end{array}
$$

So I equate $(4q+3p)x+(3q-4p)=1$ and solve the simultaneous linear equations

$4q+3p=0, 3q-4p=1$. I get $p=6,q=1$

Hence $6x+1$ is the required inverse.

I am pretty sure that the answer is correct but is the method to achieve it right?

Comment: LaTeX has `\langle` and `\rangle` for angled brackets, as with $\langle x^2+1\rangle$.

Comment: @alex.jordan Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denotes the ring of $p$-adic integers. You mean the residue class ring $\mathbb{Z}/p$, resp. the field $\mathbb{F}_p$. Also, you forgot to write down the variable $x$ in the polynomial ring. I've made an edit.

Comment: Hello Sir, In the above simultaneous linear equation solving how did you get the values p=6 and q=1 .  If you substitute the values to the given equation the equation left hand side is not equal to the right hand side.  Can you please explain it

Comment: @Gopinath See modulo 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is very good. And you can check that $(4x+3)(6x+1) = 24x^2 + 22x + 3 = 2x^2 + 3 = 2(-1) + 3 = 1$ as required.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative approach, doable since the vector space here is only two-dimensional. Multiplication by $4x+3$ corresponds to the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}3&7\\4&3\end{bmatrix}$ using the basis $\{1,x\}$. This matrix has inverse $\frac{1}{-19}\begin{bmatrix}3&-7\\-4&3\end{bmatrix}\equiv\frac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}3&-7\\-4&3\end{bmatrix}\equiv4\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\7&3\end{bmatrix}\equiv\begin{bmatrix}1&5\\6&1\end{bmatrix}$, which corresponds to multiplication by $1+6x$ (upon inspecting the first column).

Comment: How did you find the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}3&7\\4&3\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Multiplying $1$ by $4x+3$ gives $4x+3$, and with respect to the basis $\{1,x\}$, that is the vector $\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\end{bmatrix}$. So the action of multiplying by $4x+3$ turns $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ into $\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\end{bmatrix}$, giving the left column. Similarly, multiplying $x$ by $4x+3$ gives $4x^2+3x\equiv-4+3x\equiv7+3x$, and with respect to the basis $\{1,x\}$, that is the vector $\begin{bmatrix}7\\3\end{bmatrix}$, giving the second column.

Comment: Wow! I like this method too.

Comment: It's as good as your ability to invert a matrix and find an inverse mod $n$. So it is less quick compared to other methods if you quotient by a higher degree polynomial or have a larger $n$.

Comment: Okay! But very nice method.